# How to capture <input type="file"> data with DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript

Without using html form, how to capture the data of `<input type="file">` using DOM manipulation especially if it's an image.

HTML:

```
<body> 
  <input type= "file">
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? There's tons of resources to help you start this

Comment: What do you mean how to capture? Your question is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Want to upload image using input file and then display it on dom, without using jquery plugins.

Comment: upload it? like to the server? or like read the file.

Comment: read the file. No server is used. No AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Tyler is right and found similar answer in MDN.

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded`

MDN reference: [MDN reference for file preview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)